# Get Paypal subscribed users programmatically

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I'm working on a Paypal subscription based website.
I can not find an API method to get my subscribed clients and their subscription's status.
I only found a file to download manually, and it is not practical to check that way.

Basically what I want is to disable users when they cancel their subscriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go would be to use IPN to notify you when the subscription is cancelled and use the notification to trigger the the action. You can have a look at the documentation [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).

Comment: He has a tag for REST, though.  IPN doesn't work with REST does it?  Wouldn't he need Webhooks instead?

Comment: Agreed, Drew. I saw the subscription tag and went with IPN but if using REST he would want to go with webhooks.